# truncate all data in model and restart the id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have several records in my Category model. All of them are test data. Now I want to clear the data.

if I issue Category.destroy_all or Category.delete_all all the records are deleted. However, any newly created record does not start with id 1. If I had 10 records previously, the new category after I destroy the previous records start at 11.

How do I force restart id from 1?

Comment: What prevents you from dropping then creating the table, That will take care of the next auto increment value as well doesn't it?

Comment: Why does it matter where the `id` values start?

Comment: Try using ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE categories")

Comment: @vinodadhikary first, I do not know how to drop the table and recreate it in rails code. I want my seeds.rb to recreate the list of categories starting from id1 everytime I run it.  bachan-smruty's solution looks good but it's too lenghty to type. I'm looking for any method in rails that can do this with less code. thanks all

Comment: @krishworks, please see my answer below.  That might be a quicker solution for you (just another rails option).

Answer (score 0):

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE #{table_name}")
```

You can run choose to run it:

1. in rails console
2. in seed.rb file if you don't have console access. (Make a method in category model that you will run only once. (`rake db:seed`))

app/model/category.rb :

```
def truncate_me!
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE #{table_name}")
end
```

db/seed.rb

```
Category.truncate_me!
```

3. in a migration

If you have access to database you can also run an actual TRUNCATE query.

Answer (score 0):

You could redo the migration with the following command:

```
rake db:migrate:redo VERSION=your_category_migration_version
```

This will drop the category table and recreate it.  If you have other migrations that change category table then you would need to run those too.

After executing the above rake task, you can run your seed task.

Comment: thanks for your quick answer. it definitely helps me to see the various rails options that I'm unaware. However, this is still a pain to remember the version number and hard code it in my seeds.rb file. I 'm looking for options that can do this similar to (and as simple as)  Category.destroy_all